# Angular issue with Angular's built in currency from CommonModule

Tags: angular, module

I am experiencing this issue in my application: "No pipe found with name 'currency'".

I have imported the CommonModule and CurrencyPipe from @angular/common in my app.module.ts and called it in my imports and providers of course.

In my accessories component, I am trying to use this currency to display a price tag underneath an item. And this is where the issue occours.

This is my accessories component's ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/products.module';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accessories',
  templateUrl: './accessories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accessories.component.scss']
})
export class AccessoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((products) => {
      this.products = products;
    });
  }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    
  }
}
```

And here is the html file where the error occours:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of products">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Price: {{ product.price | currency }}</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addToCart(product)">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In which module is your `AccessoriesComponent ` declared ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Ahh silly mistake on my part. I declared it in the wrong module. Thank You.